Pushouts in the category of integer compositions
Let $\mathsf{Comp}$ be the category with positive integers as objects and for $k \leq n$, $hom(n,k)$ is the set of integer compositions of $n$ into $k$ parts (with obvious composition of compositions). Basically this can be seen as the subcategory $\Delta_{epi}$ of epimorphisms in the simplex category $\Delta$.
I noticed that $\mathsf{Comp}$ has pushouts (just as $\Delta_{mono}$ has pullbacks), which can be described as follows:
Given a $k$-composition $\alpha$ and an $l$-composition $\beta$ of $n$, let $\gamma$ be the largest composition (in terms of the number of its parts) of $n$, such that it can be subdivided into both $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Then $k \sqcup_n l$ is the number of parts of $\gamma$.
Now, in $\Delta_{mono}$ its easy to see that the pullback of $ k \xrightarrow{\alpha} n \xleftarrow{\beta} l $ is given by
$$k\times_{n} l =|im(\alpha) \cap im(\beta)|.$$
However, I find it not so easy to give a direct (and sufficiently nice) formula for $k \sqcup_n l$ in terms of the compositions $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Can you see/are you familiar with one?

As far as I know, there is no similarly straightforward characterisation. The pushout is the quotient of the reflexive, symmetric and transitive closure of the relation $\sim$ on $[k] + [l]$ generated by $\alpha(i) \sim \beta(i)$ for all $i \in [n]$, but that's not simpler than just saying it's a pushout. This is essentially a path-finding algorithm, not something that can have a closed formula.

Hm, makes sense I guess.. thx!

Combinatorialists often tame compositions using the "partial sum" bijection: The compositions of a given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ are in bijection with the subsets of $\left[n-1\right] = \left{1,2,\ldots,n-1\right}$; the bijection sends a given composition $\alpha = \left(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_k\right)$ to the subset $\left{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \cdots + \alpha_i \mid 1 \leq i < k \right}$. Under this bijection, pushout corresponds to intersection of subsets, right?

@darijgrinberg i think that's pretty much the idea of my answer below

@BipolarMinds: Ah, I see, because monos in $\Delta$ are subsets and their pullbacks are intersections.

yes (with $\gamma_i$s being the partial sums)

I think the situation is dual to the $\Delta_{mono}$ case, in the following sense:
Let $\gamma:[n] \to [k]$ be a morphism in $\Delta$. For $i \in \{ 0, \dots, k  \} $ we set $$\gamma_i = | \gamma^{-1}\left( \{ 0, \dots , i\} \right)|.$$ Clearly, $0 \leq \gamma_0 \leq \gamma_1 \leq \dots \leq \gamma_k = n+1$. If $\gamma \in \Delta_{epi}$, the inequalities are strict and we obtain a morphism $\bar{\gamma} \in \Delta_{mono}([k],[n])$.
In particular, a span $[a] \xleftarrow{\alpha} [n] \xrightarrow{ \beta} [b]$ in $\Delta_{epi}$ gives rise to a cospan $[a] \xrightarrow{\bar{\alpha}} [n] \xleftarrow{ \bar{\beta}} [b]$ and the pushout of the first should be isomorphic to the pullback of the second (for which we have a formula).
